# How to start a phone call from the terminal in Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

The ability to start a phone call from the terminal is mentioned in this transcript of a [Q&A-session with the Canonical community team](http://thebluedrag.blogspot.de/2015/08/ubuntu-q-18082015.html).

So - did somebody figure out, how to do it? The terminal app for Ubuntu Phone/Touch is a powerful tool.

**Edit:**
I tried to start `dialer-app` via terminal (terminal app) on my BQ Aquaris E5 HD Ubuntu Edition [Ubuntu 15.04 (OTA-9.1)] with

`sudo dialer-app`

As a result I get the following error:

`QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display`

I tried to google this error, but I was not able to link the suggested solutions to my problem.

Comment: So I can't parse the code particularly well, but here's the source: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~phablet-team/dialer-app/trunk/view/head:/src/dialerapplication.cpp and you'll notice that there's some command line usage arguments, like tel:///

Comment: So it should be possible to dial with `dialer-app tel [number]`?

Comment: it is a link address - type it into the browser. ex:  tel:///###-###-####   technically you should be able to launch from terminal, but it seems there are several things like the display server, and security getting in the way for launching...

Comment: Better suited for [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do in this way:

```
ubuntu-app-launch dialer-app tel:///###-###-####
```

Comment: That starts the dialer-app and preselects the number. You still have to press the green "start call" button. But this is probably as good as it gets. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It works even on locked screen, just run script

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ /usr/share/ofono/scripts/dial-number /ril_0 +7800xxxxxxx
```

you`ll get

```
Using modem /ril_0
/ril_0/voicecall01
```

where /ril_0 is the use SIM1 and +7800xxxxxxx is phone number you need

use `/usr/share/ofono/scripts/list-contexts` and `/usr/share/ofono/scripts/list-modems` to get more info

Read more here [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Basic Calling](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Basic%20Calling)